# How does Dynamic Dns works?

Tags: networking

In order to access computer from anywhere we need ipaddress but as we know dynamic ip address changes frequently . To come up this issue Dynamic Dns is used .Can anyone please tell me how does it works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic DNS works in such a way that you have a client running on the router or an internal machine that continuously monitors the public IP, and when it changes, it sends an update to a remote server informing them of the change.  Once the remote server receives the updated IP, all relevant DNS records are updated with the new information.

There are a few potential problems with this technology, but they are minor in my opinion.

Problem 1: Cached DNS records.  Intermediary DNS servers frequently will cache results to avoid excessively re-querying of the nameservers.  (this reduces delay and bandwidth)  Part of each DNS record is a "ttl" which tells the caching servers when it would be appropriate to expire the cached records.  It is likely that there will be a delay between when the IP is updated and when the cache will expire.

Problem 2: Behind a NAT.  Even though the dyn-dns clients are capable of identifying your public IP address, they cannot adjust firewall rules upstream.  If you're behind any sort of NAT, it is unlikely that services hosted behind the NAT would be accessible from the public Internet.  You must adjust firewall rules to point your public IP to your devices.  This won't be possible if you do not control the firewalling equipment.  (Public hotspot?)

Problem 3: Free DYNDNS providers delete stale records.  If your IP doesn't change for a long period of time, or your client dies and stops updating your records, your DYNDNS provider may delete your account/records due to inactivity.

Problem 4: Services using DYNDNS providers are typically already given a warning flag from most security appliances/systems.  Because of the anonymity of DYNDNS, hackers frequently make use of such services, and many security companies will treat services on DYNDNS as a higher risk, and configure their threat-detection accordingly.  This can cause unexpected issues and troubleshooting headaches.

In conclusion: for personal use, DYNDNS can be very helpful to connect back to your home-office or personal computers... but it definitely is not suitable for a business website or service.

Answer (score 2):

So, when you register with a provider of Dyanmic DNS (i.e. www.noip.com), it will install a program on your computer that will link to your dynamic DNS account for say (www.mycustomurl.com) that will map that website of .mycustomurl.com to whatever your at the time external IP address is.

So fundamentally, it checks:

- Your external IP doing a routine check (you set the interval time for checks/updates)
- Links that, at the time dynamic external IP address to your DNS account
- Updates the DNS record to point whichever domain/subdomain you provide (alternatively, they can provide you a custom url from the provider, i.e. xxxxx.noip.com
- Repeats the process if the IP changes.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of being pedantic, I think that several things are missing here.
First of all Dynamic DNS is not a program or a (commercial or non commercial) service, it is a protocol defined by the IETF task force in [RFC 2136](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2136) and updated in [RFC 3007](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3007). It defines a standard way to update the records of a DNS server on-the-fly (no need to modify the configuration files and restart / HUP the service).

The Dynamic DNS protocol is nowadays massively used between a master and its slaves to automatically update them when a modification is detected without the hassle of doing it by yourself.

Regarding the security issues noted by @TheCompWiz allow me to disagree if it is about the protocol (and not the DynDNS service, which seems to be the case here). Dynamic DNS is not anonymous (and can / should even be secure with TSIG keys) since a check on the emitter's IP is possible, and is extremely used in medium to large sized companies. A somewhat easy workaround that would cost ~$15/y would be to rent your own domain name and maintain it yourself (or find someone who can do it for you and allow you to perform Dynamic DNS queries to update the records).